# How to inherit controller of a third party module for customization Odoo 12?

Tags: python, odoo, web-controls, odoo-12

I have a module with a controller and I need to inherit it in a newly created module for some customization. I searched about the controller inheritance in `Odoo` and I found that we can inherit Odoo's base modules' controllers this way:

`from odoo.addons.portal.controllers.portal import CustomerPortal, pager as portal_pager, get_records_pager`

but how can I do this for a third party module's controller? In my case, the third party module directory is one step back from my own module's directory. If I should import the class of a third party module controller, how should I do it?

Comment: It is not a problem whether you are using a custom module.If the module installed in the database you can import as 'from odoo.addons'.
Eg : from odoo.addons.your_module.controllers.main import MyClass

Comment: @AjmalJK That is the answer, you should post it as one ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a problem whether you are using a custom module.If the module installed in the database you can import as from `odoo.addons`.

Eg : `from odoo.addons.your_module.controllers.main import MyClass`